# Convert - -(double dash) to -> automatically in SublimeText 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

During my work I use -> many times and on a hungarian keyboard there is no dedicated > button, so I have to use 3 keys to enter this and sometimes I also misstype.
Is there a way to convert -- (double dash) automatically a ->? Snippet is not so good because it requires a TAB to convert.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this should rather be done at the level of the operating system. Which system do you use?

Comment: Win7, but I don't think I would like this conversation outside of Sublime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this with a simple key binding such as the following:

```json
{
    "keys": ["-", "-"],
    "command": "insert", "args": {
        "characters": "->"
    },
},
```

Now when you type `--` as soon as you hit the second `-` it triggers and replaces the text with `->` like you want.

Note however that this would apply to every usage of the text `--` in every file. This could be constrained to some degree by using a `context` in the key binding that makes it apply only in certain files, such as this one that ensures that the binding is only valid in plain text files:

```json
{
    "keys": ["-", "-"],
    "command": "insert", "args": {
        "characters": "->"
    },
    "context": [
        { 
            "key": "selector", 
            "operator": "equal", 
            "operand": "text.plain", 
            "match_all": true 
        },

    ],
},
```

This can be applied to any scope you want; use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name...` from the menu while editing a file to determine the scope that you need (generally you probably want only the first scope item).

Either way, this makes it impossible to type `--` directly without including a deliberate long pause between the two `-` characters or doing a backspace. That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, works as I wanted. The scope I use is embedding.php where I never use more than one dash, so thanks again!